# Google Analytics not working as expected on Aurelia TypeScript project?

Tags: typescript, google-analytics, aurelia

I am new to Google Analytics and I want to set it up for a website that I am developing.

**Current situation**

I have set up Google Analytics in my project by adding the following code to my index.ejs, now the code looks as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-162300254-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-162300254-1');
</script>
    <title><%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.title %></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <base href="<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">
    <!-- imported CSS are concatenated and added automatically -->
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.server) { %>
    <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
    <script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I have added the code that I received from Google Analytics to this file.

This seems to trigger something because now I can see that there is one active user if I am testing my website locally.

**The problem**

I can not even see which page is getting visited the most, I can not see on Google Analytics which pages I did visit. On the tab "Active pages" it only shows one page which is apparently called "/".

I have a feeling that I missed something while setting it up because this does not give me much insight into the data on my website.

If something is unclear, please let me know.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are going to be very important for you and running a website with Aurelia with any sort of Google Analytics and SEO.

Firstly, and this is the big one. You'll want to use [Rendertron](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) to use a headless client to serve your aurelia app. This is the best way for SEO to capture proper information for your aurelia app.

Secondly, you'll want to ensure **Push State is Enabled** You can do this by adding the following code your your `configureRouter` function

```js
configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.options.pushState = true;
```

I use google analytics for 3 of my aurelia apps and with both of these on and working you will get proper information about every page. Previously to be doing both of these, I only saw the `/` route as you were mentioning. Good luck and sorry it took two days to get a response on your question.

Comment: Hello Collin. Thanks for your answer, I've added the code that you sent in the configureRouter method. Is Rendertron required to make this work? Since I am not to sure if the company wants to use this.

Comment: Hello @zerk It is not a requirement but you won't have ANY SEO on your aurelia site until you start using Rendertron. Your site will JUST be your index.html page with none of the written View's, as that is how all SPA's work. Rendertron is what takes ur SPA and turns it into a multiple page SEO view for Bots crawling your website. Highly suggested if you want any sort of proper indexing.

Comment: While it's true that some kind of backend rendering makes sense for SEO purposes I just want to point out that there are many alternatives. SSR in Aurelia can solve it without any 3rd party rendering, prerender.io and rendertron like you mention @CollinHerber. When it comes to google I'm pretty sure they're rendering pages and manages to index them, but it won't work for many other spiders.

Comment: Reading the answer again, it doesn't answer your question at all, it's just some tips on ways you could do to improve indexing of your site and doesn't have anything to do with you tracking the site usage. So to answer your question, Rendertron isn't required neither is pushState

Answer (score 0):

Since your Aurelia app is a single page application aren't you actually switching pages. What I've done to get GA to work is that I'm calling a function which pushes events into window.dataLayer when a new "page" is loaded. Something along the lines of:

```
  public updateGTM(page: string, ...more data you want to push to goole): void {
    if (!(<any>window)['dataLayer']) {
      (<any>window)['dataLayer'] = [];
    }
    let gtmData: any = {
      "pageType": page,
      // ... what ever keys you're using
    };
    (<any>window).dataLayer.push(gtmData);
   }
```

then in your page in activate or attached you call that function and Google will know.

The same goes for any other type of events you want to send over, you push them into window.dataLayer and then your analytics script sends them over to Google.

Comment: Hmm I have added the glocalgtag script to index.ejs and added the mothod updateGTM which I call from attached. the method is called as I can see in the debugger. However, dataLayer.push does not actually call the google webservice . I was trying to send gtmData = {event: "screen_view", screen_name: "notes"} but I have tried many other tags as well. Any idea what's wrong ?